# jQuery $.extend without overriding target properties

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to extend an object without overriding the properties that are already set?
In the following example I'm looking for a way to add 2 wings to the cat, but keepings it's 4 legs.

```
var cat  = { legs: 4 };
var bird = { legs: 2, wings: 2 }

// some references in my application to the original cat
var some_cat = cat;

$.extend( cat, bird );

// expected { legs: 4, wings: 2 }
console.log( some_cat );
```

**Update**

I forgot to make it clear in the original question / example, but it is important that it modifies the original cat object.

Comment: `$.extend(bird, cat)` ?

Comment: @Brewal Your code is correct but I think Dirk's logic is that `cat` is the original object and thus put as the first argument of `$.extend`...

Comment: Indeed @silkfire , sorry my example was not really clear. I've updated the question.

Comment: If you want to keep the settings of cat, I think the "logic" would be to have `bird` as "original object" and thus put it as first argument. This is the exact behaviour you are looking for. I don't understand why it wouldn't be a solution.

Comment: Because there are already references to `cat` in my application. Switching the parameters wouldn't update the original `cat` object.

Comment: `cat = $.extend(bird, cat)` actually "updates" your original `cat` object : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f29fV/2/)

Comment: It updates the bird, too.

Comment: Then just do this : `cat = $.extend({}, bird, cat);` : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f29fV/4/)

Comment: @Brewal You're missing the point of OP. He already knows how to solve it, he just wants to know why the order of the arguments are messed up and non-logical.

Comment: How about: `var catbird = $.extend({}, bird, cat);`  This introduces the new animal without modifying the other 2.

Comment: I'm afraid your use case falls within this sentence from jQuery docs: `For needs that fall outside of this behavior, write a custom extend method instead.`

Comment: `var some_cat = cat; ` makes some_cat and cat point to the same data. Modifying one will modify the other. At first you will think the cats are imitating each other, but it will slowly drive you mad.

Comment: better read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object

Comment: @DirkBoer How can you expect the original `some_cat` to be the same as the modified `cat`?

Comment: you need `var cuddles = $.extend({}, cat)` or a cat constructor; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object -- it discusses this

Comment: @Brewal ehh yeah? That's called a reference to the same object?

Comment: With `var some_cat = cat;` you just make a new object.

Comment: in that line `some_cat` and `cat` are the same object, referred to by different vars

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like -

```
for (prop in bird) {
    if(!cat.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        cat[prop] = bird[prop];
    }
}
```

After cat = {legs: 4, wings: 2}

Comment: +1 for no jQuery ;)  Also you might want to add `var prop` instead of just `prop` to make the variable local instead of an implied global.

Comment: This seems to work - forgive me for being ignorant, but what is $.extend doing that this simple piece of JS is not doing? Is that only deep copy vs shallow copy?

Comment: No, as far as i know $.extend does not follow shallow copying. It just overrides and all the properties from object2 to object1. For more information about $.extend() [read this link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)