# merge 2 objects without overwriting "false" value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've 2 objects
`var obj1 = {a: 1, b: true, c: false};`

`var boj2 = {b: true, c: true, d: 1};`

I would like to have a union of two object like this:
`{a: 1, b: true, c: false, d: 1};`

I've tried with `$.extend` but it overwrites `c` and I obtain 
`{a: 1, b: true, c: true, d: 1};`

Some suggestions?

Comment: at the end `c` should be either `true` or `false`?

Comment: the first object values must have the priority, so it should be `false`

Comment: is it really the "false" that you want to keep, or is it that obj1 values have a higher priority than obj2?

Comment: sorry, I must just to reverse the 2 parameters in $.extend function... 
it is embarrassing, it is the fault of fatigue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reverse the order

```js
var obj1 = {a: 1, b: true, c: false}; 
var obj2 = {b: true, c: true, d: 1};
console.log($.extend(obj2,obj1));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I've put together a JSFiddle that may help solve your problem - see https://jsfiddle.net/fhjuL22s/1/

```
var obj1 = {a: 1, b: true, c: false, e: 0}; 
var obj2 = {b: true, c: true, d: 1, e: 1};

var result = {};

for (var prop in obj1){
    result[prop] = obj1[prop]
    ? (obj2.hasOwnProperty(prop) ? obj2[prop] : obj1[prop])
    : obj1[prop];
}

for (var prop in obj2) {
    if (!result.hasOwnProperty(prop))
    result[prop] = obj2[prop];
}

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try googling it? The answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590177/merge-two-objects-without-override) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18308709/jquery-extend-without-overriding-target-properties), depending on your wishes:

1. Create a new object and merge both obj1 and boj2 into that. You will end up with a new object though, so do not use this when you *need* to modify the first object. Example can be found at link 1.
2. Create your own method for this. Example can be found at link 2.